# Xcode can't read swift files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This project came to me to be updated to the new iOS 10.
It uses frameworks downloaded with cocoa pods. Some of these frameworks are written in swift.
Now that I made few changes on the project code, when I try to build the project, I get errors on the frameworks I downloaded as if the project can't read swift!

Is there somewhere where I can set my project to accept swift classes?

[image: XCode Can't read swift files]

Comment: The `open` keyword is new in Swift 3, so this looks as if you are still using Xcode 7, or Xcode 8 in legacy (Swift 2.3) mode.

Comment: I agree, I think that it's not Xcode 8, the warning/error tab that has open, should have the new Buildtime and Runtime switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Xcode to Xcode 8 and it updated the code and fixes theses issues. Thanks Folks.